# Rolling Dice 5 Times

Tags: permutations, combinations, dice

A fair 6-sided die is rolled 5 times and the result is recorded for each roll.

a) How many different sequences of results are possible?

b) Of the possible sequences of results, how many of them contain exactly 3 rolls of a 4?



I'm pretty sure part (a) is $6^5 = 7,776$.

Part (b) is really confusing me though. I think that I should be using $ _nC_r$ somehow, but I'm not sure what $n$ and $r$ should be.

Comment: First assume we have such a "good roll" with three times the $4$. How many chances we have for the positions of the $4$ in the tuple? How many chances are there to fill in the remained positions?

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $125$ simply?

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom53$ ways to select $3$ rolls out of $5$ that are destined to be the rolls that give a $4$.

For a selected roll there is $1$ possibility (it gives a $4$).

For a not selected roll (there are $2$ of them) there are $5$ possibilities (it gives no $4$).

Draw conclusions.

> So that gives $\binom531^35^2=\binom535^2=250$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), you are correct.

For (b), first, try to solve a simpler question:

> How many results contain $4$ in their first three rolls, and no $4$ after that?

Now, answer another similar question:

> How many results have a $4$ in the *last* three rolls, and no other fours?

And another similar one:

> How many results have a $4$ in positions $2,4$ and $5$, and no other fours?

---

Once you answer that question, think about

1. Are the sets of results in those three questions disjoint?
2. how many different questions of that type you can ask?
3. How many results are there, therefore, in total?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about solving any of those questions. I must be missing something fundamental about this concept.

Comment: @emw Even the first question in yellow?

Comment: @emw OK, how about this question: How many rolls have a $4$ in their first **four** rolls, and something that is not a four in the final roll?

Comment: Well that would be 5, right?

Comment: Okay. So for your first question in yellow, would that be 25 then?

Comment: or is 12 the same as 21? That would make it 15 then right?

Comment: @emw Yeah, $25$ for the first question in yellow. The order matters, unless we specifically say it doesn't.